# Refinable string not searchable

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, search, managed-property, crawled-property

I am using SharePoint Online. I created a site column "Model" which is of CHOICE type. Two crawled properties ows_Model and ows_q_CHCS_Model are created automatically by SharePoint. I used the default managed property RefinableString01 to map ows_Model.

At search centre, if I type the keyword model:GL, the search result contains the images tagged with GL, and the refinement also works.

If I type the keyword GL, the search result does not contain the images I expected to see.

From the article [What makes a SharePoint column searchable](http://www.techmikael.com/2014/07/what-makes-sharepoint-column-searchable.html), I found that the crawled property ows_Model is marked with Included in full-text index; However, the managed property RefinableString01 is marked Not searchable. It is the default value which cannot be changed. Is there any way to make this column free text searchable?

Comment: you can modify the managed property , if that doesn't help. Suggest you to create new managed property and map it to any crawl property that you need (instead of using pre-defined Refinablestring01) and have your own searchable, Queryable,Retrievable, Refinable, Sortable  and that will help in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

you can modify the managed property , if that doesn't help. Suggest you to create new managed property and map it to any crawl property that you need (instead of using pre-defined Refinablestring01) and have your own searchable, Queryable,Retrievable, Refinable, Sortable and that will help in most cases

Answer (score 0):

Solved by creating a new managed property marked with searchable, queryable, retrievable.

Comment: pls upvote if any comments helped you, I mentioned the same thing as proposed solution.